# How to use onWithOptions in Elm 0.17?

Tags: elm

I have an application where I'm selecting some statuses. Initially, I had a code like this

```
div
    [ classList
    [ onClick (SelectStatus (Just status)) ]
```

But at some moment, I need to stop event propagation. I found that there is an [onWithOptions](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-html/4.0.2/Html-Events#onWithOptions) function but I don't know how to use it. Especially what's the Decoder parameter for. I rewrite it to this form but I'm still getting some errors.

```
div
    [ onWithOptions "click" { stopPropagation = True, preventDefault = False } keyCode (SelectStatus (Just status))
```

This is the error message

```
Function `onWithOptions` is expecting 3 arguments, but was given 4.

Maybe you forgot some parentheses? Or a comma?at line 171 col 11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link is pointing to an obsolete package as of Elm 0.17. Here is the correct version: http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/1.1.0/Html-Events#onWithOptions

I think this would give you the functionality you're after:

```
onWithOptions "click" { stopPropagation = True, preventDefault = False } (Json.succeed (SelectStatus (Just status)))
```

Comment: Damn Google, I took the first link it gave me. It looked so trustworthy. Thank you very much.